# Transfer data using NDIS

Tags: visual-c++, fpga, ndis, raw-ethernet

I am working on fpga firmware, in which i want to have very fast data transfer using ethernet . I got help from FPGA forum they say that suggest designs for data transfer using light weight internet protocol (LWIP).

How this is different from transfering the data using NDIS. I will be grateful if you can suggest me some guide to interface my visual c++ application to the network guide and tranfer the data.

many greeting in advance.

Comment: can you clarify your requirements for data-rate, latency, reliability?

Answer (score 0):

LWIP is a library for talking IP on a network.
NDIS is a specification for how an OS talks to network cards.

Neither is necessarily what you appear to want.

If you want to transfer data very simply and quickly point-to-point using Ethernet, you need to understand how Ethernet works at the packet level, and form your data into some Ethernet packets.  You can make up your own protocol for this if you have control over both ends of the link.

If you want to transfer the data over an existing network topology, you would be better doing it using an existing protocol. UDP/IP might be one such protocol, depending on your requirements for data-rate, latency, software complexity, reliability etc.  LWIP is one library which implements UDP, so might be of use.

Comment: "If you want to transfer data very simply and quickly point-to-point ... if you have control over both ends of the link."                                                                           Many thanks for your great answer. Can you please provide me some more help so that i can look into it in more detail.

Comment: You need to give more detail about your problem first - how much control you have over the endpoints, whether you require routing, should it work just point-to-point or within an existing network.  What is your burst and average data rate? what end-to-end latency can you tolerate? What do you want to do with erroneous packets (drop them, retransmit them, correct them?). Update your question with these details.  If you don't have answers, you have a system design problem and you need to go up a few levels and design your *system* first.

Comment: I am using GIGABIT Network Card to transfer data to my FPGA Device. And I am using PowerPC to handle the communication at other end (in FPGA Where I am writeing this data on DDR2 ram available at FPGA.

Comment: Add the extra information to your original question where other answerers can see it please.  But it's not really enough detail yet...